# With superset installed from git clone unable to find the site-packages?

Tags: apache-superset

I have superset installed from a git clone.

All seems to be working ok but I don't have the site-packages. For example File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py" is missing

I have been looking around the official documentation but I cannot how.

Comment: What is a "superset"?

Comment: Superset is an open-source software cloud-native application for data exploration and data visualization able to handle data at petabyte scale (big data).